# UpValues evaluation with Dot operator

Tags: evaluation, upvalues

I would like to simplify some database notation, and I'm doing some tests with `UpValues` for that.

For example, if I set this Upvalue fot tab1:

```
tab1 /: tab1.column1 = 1
```

When I evaluate

```
tab1.column1
```

I get `1` as expected. But if later I set `column1 = "x"`, when I evaluate it again, I get `tab1."x"` instead of `1` as I need.

There is some way that I can change this behavior? So I could get `1` and prevent variables name conflict?

**Update**

To avoid misinterpretation here is the evaluation sequence.

Quit the kernel and evaluate:

```
tab1 /: tab1.column1 = 1;
column1 = "x";
tab1.column1
```

The result is `tab1."x"` in the first evaluation.

Comment: I get `1`, as expected, in version 9.0.0 (Windows Vista).

Comment: @kguler Hi.. Strange behavior... see post update.

Comment: I can't reproduce either of the reported behaviors. On OS X, V9.0.0, I get `tab1."x"` for all evaluations of `tab1.column1`. That's what I would expect because I think the ownvalue for `column1` is in inserted into `Dot` before `tab1` is checked for upvalues.

Comment: @m_goldberg it's this. The if you do `Unprotect@Dot; SetAttributes[Dot, HoldAll]` it will works as I need, but now I'm looking for some way to do that without use `Unprotect@Dot` (I don't know if it's possible). Another test is `tab1.Unevaluated@column1`. Tks.

Comment: @Murta Very closely related (perhaps a duplicate?): http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/4161/short-syntax-for-accessing-systemutilitieshashtableadd-and-systemutilitiesha The trick is to create a localized scope for the modifications using `Internal`InheritedBlock`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do:

```
Unprotect[Dot];
SetAttributes[Dot, HoldAll]
```

Then

```
   tab1 /: tab1.column1 = 1 ;
   column1 = "x";
   tab1.column1
```

returns 1

Is this what you want?

Comment: Yes!.. it's this! But it's safe? There is some way to do it in the moment of define the  UpValue, (without change `Dot`)?

Comment: I was thinking in something like `tab1 /: Dot[tab1, x_] := Dot[tab1, Unevaluated@x]` but it does not works.

Comment: It's safe. But why do you really want to do this? I would rather invent new Mathematica or DatabaseLink - like functions to do what you want.

Comment: You can see the application in the Updated part of [this post](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/16322/2266). I really don't like the way I handle database table today. I'm seeking some way to make the code better.

Comment: Hi Rolf!.. I just discovery that **Unprotect Dot is dangerous**. Today I discovery that `DateRange` do not work if we set `SetAttributes[Dot, HoldAll]`

Comment: Hi Murta. OK. You could try to use ** instead, i.e., NonCommutativeMultiply

Answer (score 4):

You could introduce your own notation. Something like the following.

```
SetAttributes[qualifed, HoldAll]
Needs["Notation`"]
Notation[ParsedBoxWrapper[
  RowBox[{"u_", "∘", "v_"}]] \[DoubleLongLeftRightArrow] 
   ParsedBoxWrapper[RowBox[{"qualifed", "[", RowBox[{"u_", ",", "v_"}], "]"}]]]
TagSetDelayed[qualifed, qualifed[u_, v_] = val_, TagSet[u, qualifed[u, v], val]]

tab1∘col1 = 1; tab1∘col1
```

> 1

```
col1 = 42; tab1∘col1
```

> 1

```
tab1∘col1 = 42; tab1∘col1
```

> 42

I'm using `\[SmallCircle]`  (`∘`) in place of dot (.). It can be entered with [esc]sc[esc]. I've tested this only a little. I'm not sure it's foolproof.

Comment: Interesting approach. Tks!

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure you're not looking for this:

```
tab1 /: tab1.column1_ := 1;
```

That is whatever `column1` binds to rather than the literal column1?

this way

```
tab1."x"
```

evaluates to

> 1

Comment: Today I know that use columns names as symbol instead of strings create a lot of troubles. But tks +1

Comment: But this approach would also work with symbols: tab1.anothercolumn evaluates to 1 as well